# Coda-Slider Problem in ie7, need to remove horizontal scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-7, horizontal-scrolling, coda-slider

I am having a big issue with coda-slider and ie7. The horizontal scrollbar is unwanted and I cannot figure out how to remove it. Since coda-slider works as one long scrolling div, I could see why this is happening, however, in all other broswers, including ie8, there is no horizonal scroll.

Looking through the web there are alot of sites saying "overflow-x:hidden" will work on the body selector in css, however this has not solved the issue.

the site is at http://www.clearcreativegroup.com/clear3/index.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In codaslider2 css - miscellaneous section, change `overflow: auto` to `hidden`

```
/* Miscellaneous */
.coda-slider-wrapper { clear: both; overflow: hidden }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove only one scrollbar in internet explorer 7. But you could set the "unofficial" html attribute "scroll" to "no" to hide both scrollbars.